# Qtwebsockets Samples SSL

Tags: qt, ssl, qtwebsockets

I am trying to use qtwebsockets but I've got problems with the ssl echoserver and client.
My project is developed in QT 5.3.2 MiniGW windows 8 64 bit, I can succesfully use the non ssl server sample but when i try to use the ssl one this is what I get :

1)Client completely black

2)Server prints three messages:

QIODevice::read: device not open
QIODevice::read device not open
SSL Echo Server listening on port 1234

I think it's a ssl problem but I am not 100% sure, I tried to install the openssl binary without
success, I hope somebody can help me.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is the problem:

The error is related to the fact that the sample looks for certificates inside the wrong directory in my system and if you want to make it running you need to go inside  sslechoserver.cpp looking for localhost.cert and localhost.key and to let the system point at the correct location inside the sample directory.

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution! This solved my problem. Unfortunately QtCreator doesn't copy the certificate files from the source directory into the build directory. If you do it manually it works.